SELECT query from two tables
Consider two tables: ANALITIC and INTRAT.
In ANALITIC I have REGISTRATION_DATE as date of registration and REGISTRATION_NUMBER as number of registration. The same REGISTRATION_NUMBER could be linked to different REGISTRATION_DATE (eg. the REGISTRATION_NUMBER 2 may be linked to REGISTRATION_DATE 01/02/2023 and 03/04/2023, format DD/MM/YYYY). I have to consider the registrations linked to a certain REGISTRATION_CODE.
For each one of these REGISTRATION of 2023 (01/01/2023 - 31/12/2023) I have to find, if present, a link to INTRAT_BILL available on table INTRAT. On the table INTRAT for the same REGISTRATION_DATE and REGISTRATION_NUMBER I can have one INTRAT_BILL, more than one INTRAT_BILL, or no one INTRAT_BILL. From table INTRAT I have to obtain the INTRAT_VALUE linked to INTRAT_BILL.
Tried a LEFT JOIN between ANALITIC and INTRAT based on REGISTRATION_DATE but received results regarding older dates.
SELECT
    a.REGISTRATION_NUMBER
    a.REGISTRATION_DATE
    a.REGISTRATION_CODE
    i.INTRAT_BILL
    i.INTRAT_VALUE
FROM
    ANALITIC a
LEFT JOIN
    INTRAT i
ON
    a.REGISTRATION_DATE = i.REGISTRATION_DATE
WHERE
    a.REGISTRATION_DATE BETWEEN '20230101' and '20231231' AND
    a.REGISTRATION_CODE = '222222'
ORDER BY
    a.REGISTRATION_DATE, a.REGISTRATION_NUMBER;


a.REGISTRATION_DATE BETWEEN '20230101' and '20231231'

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; and the expected output for that sample data.


You are not correlating on registration_number
A DATE data-type is a binary data-type consisting of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It ALWAYS has those 7 components and it is NEVER stored in any particular human readable format. When you see the date in the format DD/MM/YYYY this is the client application (SQL Developer) displaying the binary data in a way that it thinks you can understand it - the database still stores all 7 components but the client is only chosing to show you the year-month-day components. This means that when you filter using BETWEEN '20230101' and '20231231' you are asking the SQL engine to implicitly convert the strings to dates and will miss any dates between 2023-12-31 00:00:01 and 2023-12-31 23:59:59.
You are missing commas between terms in the SELECT clause.

Like this:
SELECT a.REGISTRATION_NUMBER, -- missing comma
       a.REGISTRATION_DATE,   -- missing comma
       a.REGISTRATION_CODE,   -- missing comma
       i.INTRAT_BILL,         -- missing comma
       i.INTRAT_VALUE
FROM   ANALITIC a
       LEFT JOIN INTRAT i
       ON     a.REGISTRATION_DATE   = i.REGISTRATION_DATE
          AND a.registration_number = i.registration_number -- added comparison
WHERE  a.REGISTRATION_DATE >= DATE '2023-01-01' -- use date literals not strings
AND    a.REGISTRATION_DATE <  DATE '2024-01-01' -- include the entire year
AND    a.REGISTRATION_CODE = '222222'
ORDER BY
       a.REGISTRATION_DATE,
       a.REGISTRATION_NUMBER;

Without a minimal representative example including sample data and a description of your expected output it is difficult to test.

It seems like you're encountering issues with your query retrieving older dates and possibly not properly filtering results based on the REGISTRATION_CODE. Let's refine your query to ensure it retrieves the correct data for registrations in 2023 linked to a specific REGISTRATION_CODE and their corresponding INTRAT_BILL and INTRAT_VALUE, if available.
We'll use a LEFT JOIN to ensure we retrieve all registrations from ANALITIC in 2023 and then match them with any corresponding entries in INTRAT. We'll also filter the results to only include entries with the specified REGISTRATION_CODE.
Here's how you can adjust your query:
SELECT
    a.REGISTRATION_NUMBER,
    a.REGISTRATION_DATE,
    a.REGISTRATION_CODE,
    i.INTRAT_BILL,
    i.INTRAT_VALUE
FROM
    ANALITIC a
LEFT JOIN
    INTRAT i
ON
    a.REGISTRATION_NUMBER = i.REGISTRATION_NUMBER
    AND a.REGISTRATION_DATE = i.REGISTRATION_DATE
WHERE
    a.REGISTRATION_DATE BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31'
    AND a.REGISTRATION_CODE = '222222'
ORDER BY
    a.REGISTRATION_DATE, a.REGISTRATION_NUMBER;

In this adjusted query:

We join ANALITIC and INTRAT tables based on both REGISTRATION_NUMBER and REGISTRATION_DATE to ensure we're matching the correct registration entries.
We've corrected the date format in the WHERE clause to YYYY-MM-DD, which is the standard SQL date format. This should ensure proper date filtering.
We filter results based on the specified REGISTRATION_CODE.
We've added aliases (a for ANALITIC and i for INTRAT) for better readability and maintenance.

Make sure that both REGISTRATION_DATE and REGISTRATION_NUMBER are indexed in both tables for better performance, especially if the tables are large.

"We've corrected the date format in the WHERE clause to YYYY-MM-DD, which is the standard SQL date format." A DATE is a binary data-type and has no default format (and always has a time component). If you are talking about the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT (which is used to implicitly convert from strings to DATE data types) then, again, there is no single default value as it is dependent on the NLS_TERRITORY. See this answer Oracle's default DATE format for more details.

Also, this would still exclude dates between 2023-12-31 00:00:01 and 2023-12-31 23:59:59 from the output.

A bit off topic, but still: Using a string literal with or without the DATE prefix, is not really portable to other databases (i.e. our customer may have different nls settings).
So when you're comparing a date column or a date var to a certain date, I suggest you use the to_date function:
where  a.registration_date >= to_date('2023-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
and    a.registration_date <  to_date('2024-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')


Please do provide some sample data and expected result next time.
Since your question says "I have to find, if present, a link to INTRAT_BILL available on table INTRAT" - you should add another condition in your Where clause to exclude rows that don't have an INTRAT_BILL or just change LEFT into INNER JOIN.
Tryed to construct some sample data to work with:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    analitic (REGISTRATION_NUMBER, REGISTRATION_DATE, REGISTRATION_CODE) AS
        (   Select 1, DATE '2023-02-01', '222222' From Dual Union All 
            Select 1, DATE '2023-04-03', '222222' From Dual Union All 
            Select 1, DATE '2024-03-17', '222222' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, DATE '2023-06-23', '222222' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, DATE '2023-11-19', '111111' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, DATE '2023-05-20', '222222' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, DATE '2023-01-05', '111111' From Dual Union All
            Select 5, DATE '2023-09-11', '333333' From Dual Union All
            Select 5, DATE '2024-02-02', '222222' From Dual 
        ), 
    intrat (REGISTRATION_NUMBER, REGISTRATION_DATE, INTRAT_BILL, INTRAT_VALUE) AS
        (   Select 1, DATE '2023-04-03', 101, 10 From Dual Union All 
            Select 1, DATE '2023-04-03', 102, 24 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, DATE '2023-04-03', 103, 12 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, DATE '2024-03-17', 104, 11 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, DATE '2024-03-17', 105, 13 From Dual Union All
            Select 3, DATE '2023-05-20', 106,  7 From Dual Union All
            Select 4, DATE '2023-01-05', 107,  6 From Dual Union All
            Select 5, DATE '2024-02-02', 108, 17 From Dual Union All 
            Select 5, DATE '2024-02-02', 109, 18 From Dual
        )

Below is your code corrected in a way described in other answers with the additional where condition to exclude rows with no bill.
The same could be done if you change Left into Inner join - then this condition could be ommited...
--      S Q L :
SELECT      a.REGISTRATION_NUMBER, a.REGISTRATION_DATE, a.REGISTRATION_CODE, i.INTRAT_BILL, i.INTRAT_VALUE
FROM        ANALITIC a
LEFT JOIN   INTRAT i    ON( a.REGISTRATION_NUMBER = i.REGISTRATION_NUMBER And 
                            a.REGISTRATION_DATE = i.REGISTRATION_DATE
                          )
WHERE       i.REGISTRATION_NUMBER Is Not Null And   -- this condition is added 
            a.REGISTRATION_DATE >= DATE '2023-01-01' And 
            a.REGISTRATION_DATE < DATE '2024-01-01' And
            a.REGISTRATION_CODE = '222222'
ORDER BY    a.REGISTRATION_DATE, a.REGISTRATION_NUMBER, i.INTRAT_BILL;

... with above sample data result would be:
/*    R e s u l t :
REGISTRATION_NUMBER REGISTRATION_DATE REGISTRATION_CODE INTRAT_BILL INTRAT_VALUE
------------------- ----------------- ----------------- ----------- ------------
                  1 03.04.23          222222                    101           10
                  1 03.04.23          222222                    102           24
                  1 03.04.23          222222                    103           12
                  3 20.05.23          222222                    106            7  */

